# Why memory is not allocated to byte array instantly in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

It is a simple console application with byte array creation. If commenting out the for loop of assigning value to its elements, the memory it takes while running is about 12 MB. But if enable the for loop, the memory it takes while running is about 256MB.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1000 * 1000];
//for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
//{
//    buffer[i] = 0;
//}
Console.Read();
```

So, while the byte array is created, the memory is not allocated instantly, right? What is the design behind it?

Comment: I would assume the variable gets optimised away as it's not referenced anywhere.

Comment: One possibility is that the JIT optimizer is simply removing the unused variable, as orhtej2 suggested. Another possibility is that you're running in Windows, which uses demand-paged virtual memory, so the memory is being allocated and reserved, but you're not looking at the right column in Task Manager. (Task Manager is not a memory profiler.)